# matlab: tricky vectorization of a loop where n-th value in depends on the n-th and n+k-th values

Tags: matlab, vectorization, bsxfun

This is a looped version of a matlab program that works on an array of 55 values, the tricky part is that n-th value is being updated from the n-th and (n+31)-st, and in the second case, it's (n-24)-th.

```
oldval = rand(1,55);

for j1 = 0:23
    new_random = oldval(j1 + 1) - oldval(j1 + 31 + 1);
    if (new_random < 0.0)
        new_random = new_random + 1.0 ;
    end
    oldval(j1 + 1) = new_random ;
end

for j1 = 24:54
    new_random = oldval(j1 + 1) - oldval((j1 - 24) + 1);
    if (new_random < 0.0)
        new_random = new_random + 1.0 ;
    end
    oldval(j1 + 1) = new_random ;
end
```

I am having really hard time vectorizing this code, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do have done it in two stages, one for each loop of the original code. But because of the data dependency in the second loop, you need to break the second loop further into two stages and thus have a vectorized code corresponding to those three stages. Here's the final implementation -

```
%// Initialize a new array with a copy of the input array
oldval_vect = oldval;

%// Vectorize the first loop that sets the elements 1 to 24
loop1_diff = oldval(1:24) - oldval(32:55);
loop1_add = double(loop1_diff<0) + loop1_diff;
oldval_vect(1:24) = loop1_add;

%// Vectorize the second loop for setting the rest of the elements.
%// Now, within the second loop, there is data dependency after the first 
%// 24 elements of the input array are accessed, so we need to break this 
%// second loop into two parts, one that sets elements from 25 till 48 and 
%// the next one that does from 49 till 55.
loop2_part1_diff = oldval_vect(25:48) - oldval_vect(1:24);
loop2_part1_add = double(loop2_part1_diff<0) + loop2_part1_diff;
oldval_vect(25:48) = loop2_part1_add;

loop2_part2_diff = oldval_vect(49:55) - oldval_vect(25:31);
loop2_part2_add = double(loop2_part2_diff<0) + loop2_part2_diff;
oldval_vect(49:55) = loop2_part2_add;
```